# Showing a function is bounded & continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Here's the question: Let $M$ be any metric space with metric $d$. Fix a point $p \in M$ and for each $q \in M$ define the function $f_q(x) = d(q, x) - d(p, x)$. Prove that $f_q$ is a bounded continuous function of $x \in M$.

I'm a bit confused; the problem says nothing about compactness of $M$, so how exactly is this true? Why must $f_q$ be bounded?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality to prove that $|d(q,x) - d(p,x)| \le d(p,q)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $d(x,y) \ln \delta/2$ and $f:M->R $ so $d(f_q(x),f_q(y))=|f_q(x)-f_q(y)|$

$$|f_q(x)-f_q(y)| = |d(q,x)- d(p,x)-d(q,y)+d(p,y)|\leq |d(q,x)- d(q,y)-d(p,x)+d(p,y)|$$

$$\leq|d(q,x)- d(q,y)|+|-d(p,x)+d(p,y)|\leq2d(x,y)\lneq \delta $$

so $f_q$ is continious and also bounded becouse $|f_q(x)|\leq d(p,q)$ where p and q are fixed.